# Hypothetical concerted process feasibility

Tags: reaction-mechanism

How feasible is the following hypothetical reaction, where both C and D are awful leaving groups (so the reaction must happen in one step)?

[image]

I don't see a way how the orbitals could interact, so I think that such a transformation could only occur intermolecularly. I need a second opinion.

Comment: One example of this could be the reaction of fluorine gas with oxygen gas to form FOOF.  C and D are both F and A and B are both O.  This occurs by a free-radical mechanism I believe.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dioxygen_difluoride

Comment: But it can't be concerted and intramolecular, right?

Comment: The process you describe seems very improbable. The reverse reaction will be synchronous syn- addition, which does exist, but I don't think it is true concerted process in a sense of orbital control.
Other limit is the [2+2] cycloaddition, but there is a C-D bond even in reactants.